# faster way to make a 3D blob with python?

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, mayavi, density-plot

Is there a better way to make a 3D density function?

```
def make_spot_3d(bright, spread, x0,y0,z0):
    # Create x and y indices
    x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    y = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    z = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)

    X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
    Intensity = np.uint16(bright*np.exp(-((X-x0)/spread)**2
                                        -((Y-y0)/spread)**2
                                        -((Z-z0)/spread)**2))

    return Intensity
```

The function can generate a 3D numpy array which can be plotted with mayavi[image]

However when the function is used to generate a cluster of spots (~100) as follow:

```
Spots = np.asarray([make_spot_3d(100,2, *loc) for loc in locations])
cluster = np.sum(Spots, axis=0)
```

yielding for example:

[image]
The execution time is around  1 minute (cpu i5);I bet this could be faster.

Comment: How about making one blob archtype and then scaling and shifting it?  (For this also, the scaling can be made faster depending on the accuracy and range on sizes you need, so specifying that may be helpful).

Comment: Yes, I see how to scale (*k). For shifting, I am afraid not to find a solution since I need the spots to be uniformely distributed on a sphere (I used the code from alleo http://bit.ly/1eNaH4z) so the position are precalculated

Comment: I don't think what you say rules out scaling.  Could you please explain more.

Comment: scaling is ok for eg:
 `bigger_blob = 2 * blob' where blob is 3D numpy arrayof int16. My problem is to shift (in fact rotation) to bring the blob at new positions.

Comment: I'm completely unconvinced, but you seem uninterested in really exploring this possibility, or giving me the information I'd need to explore it, so I'm going to drop it.

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you couldn't use mayavi's built-in spherical primitives, e.g. using `mlab.points3d` and passing in the `s=` parameter to control the blob size?

Comment: @ali_m:yes mayavi is just for visualisation, I need 3D gaussian function

Comment: @tom10: I am not uninterested at all by moving transforming one spot. This is just that I don't know yet how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An obvious improvement would be to use broadcasting to evaluate your intensity function over a 'sparse' mesh rather than a full `meshgrid`, e.g.:

```
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, sparse=True)
```

This reduces the runtime by a factor of about 4x on my machine:

```
%timeit make_spot_3d(1., 1., 0, 0, 0)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop 

%timeit make_spot_3d_ogrid(1., 1., 0, 0, 0)
1 loops, best of 3: 359 ms per loop
```

You can get rid of the overhead involved in the list comprehension by vectorizing the calculation over locations, spreads and brightnesses, e.g.:

```
def make_spots(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0):

    # Create x and y indices
    x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    y = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    z = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)

    # this will broadcast out to an (nblobs, ny, nx, nz) array
    dx = x[None, None, :, None] - x0[:, None, None, None]
    dy = y[None, :, None, None] - y0[:, None, None, None]
    dz = z[None, None, None, :] - z0[:, None, None, None]
    spread = spread[:, None, None, None]
    bright = bright[:, None, None, None]

    # we can save time by performing the exponentiation over 2D arrays
    # before broadcasting out to 4D, since exp(a + b) == exp(a) * exp(b)
    s2 = spread * spread
    a = np.exp(-(dx * dx) / s2)
    b = np.exp(-(dy * dy) / s2)
    c = np.exp(-(dz * dz) / s2)

    intensity = bright * a * b * c

    return intensity.astype(np.uint16)
```

where `bright`, `spread`, `x0`, `y0` and `z0` are 1D vectors. This will generate an `(nblobs, ny, nx, nz)` array, which you could then sum over the first axis. Depending on how many blobs you are generating, and how large the grid is that you are evaluating them over, creating this intermediate array might become quite expensive in terms of memory.

Another option would be to initialize a single `(ny, nx, nz)` output array and compute the sum in-place:

```
def sum_spots_inplace(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0):

    # Create x and y indices
    x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    y = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    z = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)

    dx = x[None, None, :, None] - x0[:, None, None, None]
    dy = y[None, :, None, None] - y0[:, None, None, None]
    dz = z[None, None, None, :] - z0[:, None, None, None]
    spread = spread[:, None, None, None]
    bright = bright[:, None, None, None]

    s2 = spread * spread
    a = np.exp(-(dx * dx) / s2)
    b = np.exp(-(dy * dy) / s2)
    c = np.exp(-(dz * dz) / s2)

    out = np.zeros((200, 200, 200), dtype=np.uint16)

    for ii in xrange(bright.shape[0]):
        out += bright[ii] * a[ii] * b[ii] * c[ii]

    return out
```

This will require less memory, but the potential downside is that it necessitates looping in Python.

To give you some idea of the relative performance:

```
def sum_spots_listcomp(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0):
    return np.sum([make_spot_3d(bright[ii], spread[ii], x0[ii], y0[ii], z0[ii])
                   for ii in xrange(len(bright))], axis=0)

def sum_spots_vec(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0):
    return make_spots(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0).sum(0)

# some fake data
bright = np.random.rand(10) * 100
spread = np.random.rand(10) * 100
x0 = (np.random.rand(10) - 0.5) * 50
y0 = (np.random.rand(10) - 0.5) * 50
z0 = (np.random.rand(10) - 0.5) * 50

%timeit sum_spots_listcomp(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 16.6 s per loop

%timeit sum_spots_vec(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop

%timeit sum_spots_inplace(bright, spread, x0, y0, z0)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 330 ms per loop
```

Comment: wouldn't you even be able to use a factor of `spread**-2` in the `meshgrid`? and while we're at it, also include the `**-1` from the negative sign in `exp` in that?

Comment: I was really confused by that :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an i5 processor and the spots are independent from each other, it would be nice to implement multithreading. You don't necessarily require multiple *processes* as many Numpy operations release the GIL. The additional code can be quite simple:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wrap = lambda pos: make_spot_3d(100, 2, *pos)
    cluster = sum(Pool().imap_unordered(wrap, positions))
```

---

**Update**

After some testing on my PC at work I must admit that the code above is just too naive and inefficient. On 8 cores the speedup is only ~1.5 times, relative to the singlecore performance.

I still think multithreading would be a good idea, but the success depends very much on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're doing every operation in your term 8 million (=200*200*200) times; first of all, you can cut that down to 1 million (if the sphere happens to be in the center of your grid) by just calculating one eighth of if and mirroring that. Mirroring doesn't come for free, but is still far less expensive than `exp`.

Also, it's very probable that you should just stop calculation after the value of intensity has dropped to 0. Using a little logarithm magic, you can come up with a region of interest that might be much smaller than the 200*200*200 grid.